# Hole in engine of my 2011 Toyota Corolla.

Tags: engine, corolla

Few weeks ago I took my 2011 Toyota Corolla with about 80, 000 miles to PepBoys to do oil change. About a week later, I started noticing some cranking noise. One morning, about 10 day later, I was driving to work and as soon as I get on the highway and started increasing my, I started starting noticing the noise increasing and all of a sudden the check engine light and another light came on. And then I heard a very loud cranking soud and within few seconds, I heard another very loud sound, like something broke in the engine, then the engine shots off completely. The first thing that came to my mind was to take it back to PepBoys since they were the last ones to touch the engine. While at PepBoys, they took the car inside and put it up the lift. After 15 to 20 minutes, they came back and told me that there is a hole in the engine. I had told them that I want to be present when they're lifting up the car to check it but they did not.

According to them, they did their investigation and concluded that there was oil in the engine and the problem was due to the way I was driving the. So basically I was driving the car very rough, which caused something to break in the engine.

I went back home that day and noticed a lot of oil on the floor where the car has been parked. So I drove back to the location where the tow truck picked up the car, that is where the problem occurs, and you barely see oil on the floor.

I told them that there was something loose, either the drain plug or the oil filter, which caused all the oil to spill out. I even showed them the pictures but denied me saying that they're not responsible.

Are they right? Or do you think I have a case? What causes something to break in the engine? If the engine is taken apart, is it possible to know what the problem is?

I'll attach pictures later. Thanks.

Umar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If PepBoys were the last ones to touch it and the vehicle was working fine prior to your visit. The fact they would not let you check it out would have me suspicious as to why. Have an independent mechanic do a total check on the engine and take have pictures taken of the damage if possible. Then consult with a lawyer. I think these yo-yo's owe you a new engine.